# Программирование файлообменника

Tags: веб-программирование, php, веб-сервер

Уважаемые программисты, делаю файлообменник. Есть к вам несколько вопросов:

1. Как сделать так, чтобы пользователи не могли скачивать файл по прямой ссылке? Чтобы пользователь не мог передать ссылку на файл кому угодно, иначе ведь люди, у которых не должно быть доступа к какому-то файлу, смогут скачивать его?
   Короче говоря, чтобы ссылки на файл были уникальными для всех пользователей? Это вообще возможно?
2. Как организовать закачку на сервер целой папки? Или это невозможно?

Хочется от вас не готового кода, а предложений, алгоритмов, в какую сторону копать. Хотелось бы воплотить всё это самому. Спасибо!

Comment: 1. используйется сервер nginx. 
По нему доступ к папкам и подпапкам можно запретить след. образом:
http://serverfault.com/questions/137907/how-to-restrict-access-to-directory-and-subdirs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Закрыть доступ к директории с файлами через .htaccess (deny all), если в качестве сервера используете Apache. Сделать файл files.php и так же через .htaccess редиректить все запросы типа /files/.... на этот файл. а там уже логика проверки прав и отдача файла.
2. (HTML5) JS File API

Comment: 1. Используйется nginx. 
Спасибо вам за ответ!
ещё, получается, каждый раз, когда мне нужно дать доступ к этому файлу я буду ч/з .htaccess открывать доступ ко всем файлам? - а в это время этот файл может же скачать и другой человек нет?

Comment: Ещё, получается, каждый раз, когда нужно дать доступ к определенному файлу определённому пользователю, я буду через .htaccess открывать доступ ко всем файлам? Хм... получается в это время кто-то сможет скачать любой файл, пока другой будет скачивать свой запрошенный файл. Это так?

Comment: Нет. Вам не надо открывать доступ.
Доступ закрывается для внешних подключений! Из php свободно имеете доступ ко всем файлам, так и отдавайте их пользователю средствами php.

Comment: Хм, хорошо, понял, вот, кстати, ссылку нашёл для реализации вашего метода решения:

http://habrahabr.ru/post/151795/

Есть и Nginx, Apache.  
Спасибо @Hawk!

Comment: Да, хорошее решение! и есть как раз для NGINX.
Удачи Вам!